# Inkscape Layer Dialog missing row

Tags: inkscape

My Layer dialog looks like this:

[image: Dialog]
[Here it shows](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Layer_Dialog) a row of buttons including + to add a layer.
How do I get this row to display?

Ubuntu 18.04.4. LTS
Inkscape 1.0

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. The dialog is not missing. The linked image is showing the old Inkscape interface. It now looks different. [See the new interface here, outlined in red](https://imgur.com/E7HXx1k).  Unfortunately, I notice that these options appear to have little warning symbols in your example screenshot. I don't know why however.  How was the SVG created? Did you create it? Can you share the SVG on SVGshare?

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I create an svg file via `File > New` and then immediately display the Layer dialog, the warning symbols appear there.I should say that I can add a layer via the menu.

Comment: Yes, as I said, I don't know why. This might be a tech support question, and these are generally off-topic here. You might be better to check if there's anything about it on the [Inkscape bug report site](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/). Unfortunately I can't reproduce the problem, but I'm on Windows anyway, so not much help to you.

Comment: Interestingly ... I hadn't tried clicking on it (because I didn't know what it was) and it works, so just the images are missing.

Comment: In that case, there must be some application resources missing, such as icons, probably something to do with your installation.  But that's just a guess.

Comment: That's a good guess. I'll do some research and post it here if I find anything.

Comment: If you're using the AppImage, switch to the ppa.

Comment: I removed Inkscape and then installed again and the buttons have the icons.